# Combine queries to show one set of results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two separate queries where I need to match up and combine together based on a date value.

```
select convert(varchar,Delivery_Date,101) as 'Date',
sum(case when billing_group = '3' and delivery_date >= dateadd(day,datediff(day, 0, GetDate()) - 30, 0) then 1 else 0 end) as 'OR to WA'
    from orders 
    where delivery_Date >= dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, GetDate()) - 30, 0) and billing_group in ('3') 
    group by delivery_date
    order by date desc


select convert(varchar,Origin_Date,101) as 'Date',
sum(case when billing_group = '4' and origin_date >= dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, GetDate()) - 30, 0)then 1 else 0 end) as 'WA to OR'
        from orders 
        where origin_Date >= dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, GetDate()) - 30, 0) and billing_group in ('4') 
        group by origin_Date
        order by date desc
```

[image]

Please note that I am using a different date value (delivery_date) in the first query and a different for the second (origin_date)

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Some one suggested a solution - and it worked great!  By the time I tried to comment on it - the post disappeared.  many thanks!

Comment: If it was from me, it's been deleted because it's wrong.  I grouped everything by the same date column, but you group by different dates in each query.

Comment: That was EXACTLY what I was looking for. I needed to base everything on a date (but for one group of orders it was the delivery date, for the next set pickup date). My timing must have been perfect - because your solution was spot on.  Thanks MATBAILIE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want conditional aggregation, but your query offers other room for improvement:

```
select convert(varchar(255), v.thedate, 101) as [Date],
       sum(case when o.billing_group = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as [OR to WA],
       sum(case when o.billing_group = 4 then 1 else 0 end) as [WA to OR]
from orders o cross apply
     (values (case when o.billing_group = 3 then delivery_date else o.origin_date end)
     ) v(the_date)
where v.thedate >= dateadd(day, -30, cast(getdate() as date)) and
      o.billing_group in (3, 4) 
group by convert(varchar(255), v.thedate, 101)
order by v.thedate desc
```

Notes:

- Never use `varchar()` without a length parameter.  The length varies by context and it might not do what you expect.
- I am guessing that `billing_group` is a number.  If so, don't use single quotes.  *Do* use single quotes if I'm wrong.
- I cannot tell what the data type of `delivery_date` is.  It is safer to aggregate by the full expression, rather than just the column.
- Do not use single quotes for column aliases.  Only use single quotes for string and date constants.
- There is no reason to use the "trick" of adding days to `0` to remove a time component.  Instead, just convert to `date`.
- The condition on `delivery_date` does not have to appear in both the `case` expression and the `where` clause.

Comment: One query is filtered and grouped by OriginDate and the other is filtered and grouped by DeliveryDate.  I didn't notice at first either.

Comment: WHERE clause also needs to reference the output of the APPLY, which is going to (I expect) give the optimiser nightmares?

Comment: Sorry about that - I thought I put a note in my original question about it - clearly I did not.  Thanks for the catch everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Try using UNION and adding the missing columns
then do group by and ordering

```
select * from (
 convert(varchar,Delivery_Date,101) as 'Date',
sum(case when billing_group = '3' and delivery_date >= dateadd(day,datediff(day, 0, GetDate()) - 30, 0) then 1 else 0 end) as 'OR to WA',
0 as 'WA to OR'
    from orders 
    where delivery_Date >= dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, GetDate()) - 30, 0) and billing_group in ('3') 
   -- group by delivery_date
   --- order by date desc

UNION

select convert(varchar,Origin_Date,101) as 'Date',
0 as 'OR to WA'
sum(case when billing_group = '4' and origin_date >= dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, GetDate()) - 30, 0)then 1 else 0 end) as 'WA to OR'
        from orders 
        where origin_Date >= dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, GetDate()) - 30, 0) and billing_group in ('4') 
        --group by origin_Date
        --order by date desc

        ) group by [Date] 
        order by [Date] desc
```

Comment: Would give two rows per date, you need to aggregate a second time in the outer query.

Comment: Thanks very much! I will give it a shot